# Hive jobs are not running on s3n/impala failed to open hdfs files s3n://my_bucket/

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hdfs, impala

I added `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId` and `fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey` properties in `core`, `hdfs`, `hive-site.xml`. I am able to run `select * from tbl` which is on S3 and got the result with beeline. But, when I run `select count(*) from tbl`, it fails:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
       ........
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:251)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: s3n://rakeshs3 : 400 : Bad Request
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
                 ... 16 more
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:425)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:279)
              ... 29 more
```

Impala Errors:

```
Failed to open HDFS file s3n://rakeshs3/tel.txt    Error(255): Unknown error 255
```

Comment: Do you have write access on the bucket?

Comment: Yes, I gave full access to everyone.